# Kotlin + Spring Boot + SQLite save object instead of statement.executeUpdate("...")

Tags: spring, spring-boot, sqlite, kotlin

I'm working on a project that uses Kotlin, Spring Boot and SQLite, the dependency I'm using is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.16.1</version>
</dependency>
```

In this implementation Spring automatically scans for `@Entity` classes and creates the appropriate DB tables.
Right now I'm saving entries in the Db as follows:

```
var person= Person(0,"Bob")
var connection: Connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test/sqlitesample.db")
var statement: Statement = connection.createStatement()
statement.executeUpdate("insert into person values(${person.id},'${person.name}')")
```

This woks fine, but: since the table is automatically created wouldn't be posible something like:

```
var person= Person(0,"Bob")
var connection: Connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test/sqlitesample.db")
connection.save(person)//this is made up code, this method doesn't exist.
```

So the question is:

Can you ask the DB manager to Save an instance of a data object, since it used the object to create the table instead of using a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look on Spring Boot Data JPA which does exactly what you need. It provides `CrudRepository` interface which you can use to Create/Read/Update/Delete entities.

There are lot of resources on this subject. E.g. [This guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/).The guide is in Java but it doesn't make much difference.